# Checking if a function is differentiable at a point.

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be a vector space, $X= C([1-,1],\mathbb{R})$ and it has the sup-norm.

Let $L:X\to X$ be defined by $L(f)(x) = |f(x)|$.

Let $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^m$.

> I've already shown that $L$ has directional derivatives in all directions 
>   $g(x) = x^m$ for $m\geq 1$ at the point $f$.
>
> But the question is Is $L$ differentiable at the point $f$?

I was thinking I should try for $m=0$:

$L'(f; 1) =\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\big[L(f+1\cdot t)-L(1)
\big]
=
\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\big[|x+1\cdot t|-|x|
\big] = \lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}t =1 ???
$

I'm a little bit lost and this is probably all just hogwash.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a path $c: [-\varepsilon, \varepsilon
]\rightarrow (X,d)$ by $c(t)=t$. Here $t :[-1,1]\rightarrow
\mathbb{R},\ t(x)=t$ is a constant function.

Note that $d(c(s),c(t))=t-s$ for all $s<t$. That is $c$ is a
shortest path, i.e. it is a **line** through origin of vector space $X$.

Note that $L$ folds line $c$ so that it is not differentiable.

Comment: I'm grateful that you answered, but I don't understand your answer. What does the distance (assuming $d(c(s),c(t))$ is the distance) have to do with my problem? You might have answered using techniques I haven't learned (yet) or, hopefully not, used techniques I don't recall.

Comment: Consider a map $F : \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2,\ F(x,y)=(x,|y|)$, which is not differentiable. Note that $F$ folds $\{ x=0\}$ into $\{(x,y)|x=0,\ y\geq 0\}$.